# Is it possible for Azure function listening multiple blob for blob trigger

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-functions

I need to created single azure function listening for multiple blob container. Is it possible?

Answer (score 3):

No, each Azure Function has **exactly one** trigger. However, there *is* an alternative. You can implement the processing of the blob in a generic method, define several Functions and have them all call the generic method.

Something like (pseudo code):

```cs
[FunctionName("BlobTriggerContainer1")]
public static async Task Run([BlobTrigger("container1/{name}")]Stream fileBlob, string name)
{
    await DoTheMagicAsync(fileBlob, name);
}

[FunctionName("BlobTriggerContainer2")]
public static async Task Run([BlobTrigger("container2/{name}")]Stream fileBlob, string name)
{
    await DoTheMagicAsync(fileBlob, name);
}

private void DoTheMagicAsync(Stream stream, string name)
{
    // Do your (async) magic here
}
```

An alternative solution would be to use Azure Event Grid. For more info on how to combine these services, see [Tutorial: Automate resizing uploaded images using Event Grid](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/resize-images-on-storage-blob-upload-event).