# Can a blob trigger function use multiple sources and destination?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-blob-storage, azure-blob-trigger

I have an azure function blob trigger, and I want to use many sources and destinations for this function like the following example:

If the container1 is trigged, write in output1.
If the container2 is trigged, write in output2.
...

Comment: Could you please share more details what you tried and have you got any error result?

Comment: The blob trigger is a function that listen to a blob container, when a file is detected the function runs some codes. I want to do the same thing, but I want to listen to multiple containers (sources)

Comment: you probably want to have a look at evet grid trigger for blob: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-event-grid-blob-trigger?tabs=csharp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not possible to listen to multiple sources (containers) from an Azure Blob Trigger Function.

One of the solutions for this requirement given by `@Cindy Pau` and `@rickvdboschis` to use [Azure Functions Event Grid Blob Trigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-event-grid-blob-trigger?tabs=csharp) for listening to multiple containers and process the functionality according to your requirement.

Refer to these [SO Thread1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62267754/is-it-possible-for-azure-function-listening-multiple-blob-for-blob-trigger) and [SO Thread2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64455356/18935775) for more information.